# How to translate taxonomy terms displayed via an exposed filter in views?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I'm using the Views, i18nviews, and Entity Translation modules.  All of my terms have already been translated using Entity Translation.  In views displays, the translated terms appear in the correct language except in exposed filters.  In exposed filters, the terms always appear in the default language for the site.

A search of the issue queues reveals a thread of monstrous length [here](http://drupal.org/node/346028).  So, while support for this is still a work in progress, is there any way (quick and dirty hacks are ok) to get this working today?

Answer (score 0):

Editing the View, try to add a new Filter Criteria and look for one you want to translate. There should be a duplicate entry, but the second indicates: (translated). You should use add this (exposed) filter, and delete the other one.

Comment: Though (translated) filters appear for i18n taxonomy translation, they don't appear for Entity Translation...

Comment: Well then... After enabling i18n_taxonomy, does this resolves the problem?

Comment: I can't enable i18n_taxonomy.  It conflicts with Entity Translation.  My question is specifically about Entity Translation.

Comment: Some versions of i18n have conflicts with Entity but these should be circumstantial (I already had them both enabled with no problem). I would go that way. i18n_taxonomy also has this nice function i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms which is very handy when translating terms in your code. But ok, that's up to you, sorry I couldn't help you. I'll leave my answer anyway, for others info.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The filter appears, but it still only uses English values.

Answer (score 0):

1. I de-activated entity translation for taxonomy terms in the
   interface here :

/admin/config/regional/entity_translation

- This means that the translation of terms is dealt with entirely by
  the Taxonomy translation module
- It also means that the term can be translated directly from the term
  interface

  2. I added a function to a custom module in order to order things alphabetically in the exposed filter as described here :
     [How can I sort options in an exposed views filter alphabetically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23233/how-can-i-sort-options-in-an-exposed-views-filter-alphabetically)